# What HTML/CSS to use for delimited horizontal navigation?

Tags: html, css

The navigation I'm referring to looks something like this:

```
home | about | contact
```

So what's the best and most flexible HTML/CSS to use for this type of navigation? The best thing I can come up with is to wrap the delimiters in a span so that I can control the spacing around them. For example:

```
<a href="#">home</a><span>|</span><a href="#">about</a>
```

Is that the best approach?

Comment: I usually don't prefer to use '|', because you can't control it's height/width by pixels efficiently. I'll suggest having a span.space between each menu item.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-dropdown-menu/css-gradient-dropdown.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all comes down to your target browsers, and if validating as strict HTML4.01 is important to you (ie: a boss/committee thinks it's a "big deal") or not.

Personally, for purposes of nav-menus, I go the route of wrapping everything in an unordered list.

If 4.01-compliance is important, I'll wrap that in a div.nav
If html5 is cool (which it is, with an oldIE JS-shim, as long as there are no committees involved), I'll wrap everything in a `<nav id="main-nav">` or similar.

```
<ul><li><a href="/">home</a></li><li><a href="about">about</a></li></ul>
```

Then in CSS:

```css
#main-nav li { display : inline-block; list-style : none; }
```

From there, you can set your padding on each `<li>` element to whatever you want.
You can use the `:after` pseudo-selector to inject "|" or any custom image you want, after each one (and you can use the `:last-child:after` to make sure that there's no image after the last one, if that's what you want).

You can even play around with the `a`, turning it into a block-element, and playing with padding to make the entire `li` block clickable, and not just the text.

See the oldIE-compatibility hack here: [how to make clickable links bigger](http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/154/simple-css-how-to-make-clickable-areas-bigger), if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a left border to every element, *except* the first one:

HTML:

```
​<ul id="nav-list">
<li>Home</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li>Link</li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With the CSS:

```
#nav-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;   
}
#nav-list li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
​
```

**[See the above code in action on jsfiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/3Pf5p/)**
    ​
This is rather cross-browser compatible (IE7+) but it can be easily polyfilled with something like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) for IE6. Thanks to Rob W for suggesting to use border-left and first-child to reach more browsers!

Comment: Use `border-left` and [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:first-child#Browser_compatibility). Then, the code also supports IE7 and IE8.